# SPSS: How can I be certain a plot shows homoscedasticity?

Tags: regression, spss

I learned in my statistics class to plot the standardized residuals against the standardized predicted value and that if the values fit in a roughly rectangular shape, there should be homoscedasticity.
However, I find it very hard to tell in this case. To me, it does neither look obviously homoscedastic nor heteroscedastic. Can anybody help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definitive answer here because interpretation of residual plots is rather subjective, but your plot looks pretty good to me (i.e. no violation of homoscedasticity).

In my experience, if there is a violation then its pretty easy to tell as the variance of the residuals will not be constant across the predicted values. The graph below on the right shows increasing residual variance as the fitted values increase, which is a clear case of heteroscedastic residuals

[image]

Source: https://data.library.virginia.edu/diagnostic-plots/

Comment: thanks for the reply! and the added examples :) I also used the Breusch-Pagan Test to be absolut sure.